# Can I make `"#{file_name}"` simpler?

Tags: ruby, string

It looks quite verbose to write something as this `"#{file_name}"` instead of just `file_name`.

```
  def write_hello(file_name)
    File.open("#{file_name}", "w") { |file| file.puts "Hello, world! I'm Ruby :)"}
  end
```

What can I do to make it cleaner?

**Updated**

I just have ruby [naming conventions](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#naming), so I updated the `fileName` to `file_name` now.

Comment: Tangential, but those same naming conventions would want `write_hello` instead of `writeHello`. Hang in there! :D

Comment: Yeah! Thank you, just focusing on the variable names.

Comment: Next time you ask yourself _"can I do x instead of y?"_, you should just give it a try :-)

Comment: Stefan, sorry for the silly question. I tried in *IntelliJ 2018.3* but it's highlighted and worked weirdly. It's silly to ask this question, it seems now but it's just confusing at that time to me. Thank you for the ~friendly reminder~. Thank you ;)

Comment: RubyMine is more useful in that regard.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations, I am checking it now. Thank you so much ~ I was using IntelliJ compared to VSCode (even harder to use).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's needlessly verbose.

```
x = "test"
"#{x}"
# => "test"
```

It's literally the same thing in your case.

A Ruby idiomatic version of this code looks like:

```
def write_hello(filename)
  File.open(filename, "w") do |file|
    file.puts "Hello, world! I'm Ruby :)"
  end
end
```

This uses the multi-line `do ... end` form which is often a lot easier to follow and understand but is otherwise equivalent to the `{ ... }` form. New Ruby people may be a little perplexed at how `{ x: 'y' }` and `{ |x| 'y' }` are dramatically different things, so this avoids the ambiguity there.

It's not necessary to enquote something in isolation. That would be necessary if you wanted to append a file extension, like:

```
File.open("#{filename}.txt", "w") do |file|
  # ...
end
```

Where you'd call that like:

```
write_hello(:example)
```

And that would create `example.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Your code works, but is actually bad code. Indeed it should be written as `fileName`, although a Rubyist would not name a variable like that in camel case.

However, it would be better to write shorter, like

```
File.write(fileName, "Hello, world! I'm Ruby :)")
```

although you would have to explicitly add a new line character at the end if the string if you want one, as Stefan notes.

Comment: Sorry, just first time in ruby. Still have no clue how everything works. Gabbling with the basics still on...

Comment: `write` doesn't append a newline (as opposed to `puts`).